Determining Variables from Products of Variables
I think this question should have a clear answer but it is not immediately obvious to me, so maybe it's harder than I think.
I have six variables whose values I'm trying to find; let's label them $a_{1,2,3}$ and $b_{1,2,3}$. These are physical variables and the only obvious way to model the system is to write down equation for pairwise products of these variables, e.g. $a_1b_2$, $a_3b_1$, and so on. I have enough equations and constraints that I can always solve for all nine of these products.
Given the values of all nine products, how can I determine the values of the six variables?
Let all the variables be real. (Any answer is even better if there's some way to do it with all variables generally complex. My intuition is that this is not possible as six complex variables is twelve real ones and I only have nine pairwise products.)

If you have a solution, wouldn't multiplying all $a_i$ with some non-zero $c$ and dividing all $b_i$ by $c$ give you a different solution? Your pairs consist of one $a_i$ and one $b_i$, right?

@fweth Oh... you are right. That is helpful, thank you for pointing that out. :facepalm: That's surprising that I could have so much information but still be unable to solve the system.

Maybe best to delete this question now...

As indicated in the comments, the best that can be done is to determine the proportional values of the variables.
The following values are known:

$~a_1 \times (b_1 + b_2 + b_3).$
$~a_2 \times (b_1 + b_2 + b_3).$
$~a_3 \times (b_1 + b_2 + b_3).$

Assume that $~b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = n,~$ some unknown scalar,
and temporarily assume that $~n = 1.~$
This immediately gives you exact values for each of $~a_1, a_2, a_3,~$ and thus gives you an exact value for $~(a_1 + a_2 + a_3).~$
Thus, the process can now be mirrored, to produce exact values for $~b_1, ~b_2, ~b_3.~$
Then, as indicated in the comments, if you multipy each value of $~b_1, ~b_2, ~b_3~$ by some fixed non-zero number $~n,~$ you must divide each of $~a_1, a_2, a_3~$ by this number $~n.$
